# Is there a way to run sudo without running another unneccessary command?

Tags: sudo

I wanted to run two sudo commands, piping the output from one to the other. However, when I haven't entered my password for sudo recently, it prompts me for the password. The pipes and two sudos seem to screw it up, so I can't correctly enter my password.

My solution to this is to run "sudo ls" or something else that prompts me for my password, so that the piped commands will work without asking me to enter it. This got me wondering if there was a "correct" way to run sudo such that you're not also running some other pointless command. The manpage for sudo doesn't seem to say anything about this.

Comment: Do you also have root access to the server?

Comment: I do. I know of many ways around this, like the NOPASSWD example in your answer, or by just becoming root. I just wanted to know if there was a "right" way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is `sudo -v`. From the man page:

```
-v, --validate
          Update the user's cached credentials, authenticating the user
          if necessary.
```

(And the counterpart to explicitly remove the credentials: `sudo -k`)

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @WildVelociraptor for longer sessions, you may also use `sudo -s` which will open a root console, the classic alternative is also `su` to explicitly log in as `root`, but you will need to use the root password (which may be not set or different). Just type `exit` after you are done doing system tasks and return to your user.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Anthon's answer, if you have root access to the server, you can add `NOPASSWD:` in the line where you have defined your user in `/etc/sudoers`. Once `NOPASSWD:` is added, sudo won't prompt you for the password.

If this is your current line:

`myuser ALL=(ALL)  <commands>`

change it to:

`myuser ALL=(ALL)     NOPASSWD:  <commands>`

P.S: Use `visudo` to edit the /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: This would allow *myuser* to do litterally *anything* on the system, without any password needed. That's basically like making him **root**, which is what `sudo` is here to avoid.

Comment: That was only an example. The point was `NOPASSWD` . I have updated my answer to avoid confusion for upcoming viewers.